# Delphi linker can't find needed dylib when targeting in iOS?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, dylib, delphi-10.1-berlin

In trying to create an iOS app with Delphi 10.1 Berlin, I am running into link errors.

With the target as "iOS Device - 32 bit - iPhoneOS 12.1" the message is

```
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib for architecture armv7
[DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)
```

With the target as "iOS Device - 64 bit - iPhoneOS 12.1" the message is

```
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: file not found: /usr/lib/libcharset.1.dylib for architecture arm64
[DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)
```

I am a long-time VCL developer and FMX newbie.  I have been able to successfully target Android, but I have not yet successfully targeted iOS.

Thank you!

Comment: Delphi 10.1 Berlin does not support iOS 12 as you can see [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page#RAD_Studio_Berlin). AFAIK you need XCode 8.x or earlier for Berlin. That may be a problem with macOS 10.14 Mojave.

Comment: [Supported Platforms and Operating Systems](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page#RAD_Studio_Berlin) indicates that Berlin does not support iOS versions greater than 10. For built-in iOS 12 support, you'll need to upgrade to 10.3 Rio.